# how to display pdf document in aspx page using web control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a Web application, in that user can do his course by reading the PDF document. For that purpose I need to open that PDF file in new aspx page.

Is there any control to open the PDF? Or Is there any other way to open the PDF?

If you know please help me.

Thanks & Regards,
k.kavya

Comment: to open pdf you need to create an anchor tag with target to _new and url to you relative file path.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
private void ReadPdfFile()
        {
            string path = @"C:\Swift3D.pdf";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Byte[] buffer =  client.DownloadData(path);



     if (buffer != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 
            Response.AddHeader("content-length",buffer.Length.ToString()); 
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer); 
        }

    }
```

You can find more info at..
http://geekswithblogs.net/azamsharp/archive/2005/09/18/54294.aspx

---

Now your requirement is that you basically want to read a pdf file
you can use a good library for that such as iTextSharp.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

and then use it to extract the data from the pdf into a string

```
public string ReadPdfFile(string fileName)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

            currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
            text.Append(currentText);
        }
        pdfReader.Close();
    }
    return text.ToString();
}
```

then display that string into your web page....
It should'nt be difficult now..
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. but i need to display the content of pdf in aspx page itself

Comment: Though Pdf is not Natively supported by .NET, still you can acheive this by using external libraries such as iTextPdf see my updated answer on how to do this..

Comment: I need to open that pdf in page wise.. prev and Next options should be there.. and we need to keep track of page numbers till what page the user completed the course... Please help me in doing this.. I have tried may ways but unable to succed in that...

Comment: What you are actually asking is a project in itself. Though i will try to code it all for you but then it won't be possible to post the whole project on stackoverflow.

Comment: so in case you want me to code it all for you, you need to tell me the details about your project, and i assume you are from Hyderabad.

Comment: Yes i am from hyd.. Please help me on that.. In my project, People will do training by reading the pdf after the they will do certification. for that we need to open the pdf page wise and we need to save the page number, to know upto which page user has completed his course. and after completion of last page in pdf, he will press on finish button then we will update his course status as Completed

Comment: have a little idea now what you want. I will try to code that all fo you. are you targetting this on any specific framework or should i start with .net 4.5. and in case you have any fb or similiar acc. then share so that i can consult yu in case of some doubt?

Comment: we are using .net 4.0. Any networking websites are not accessible here. can you send me here itself?

Comment: Just to give you an idea of the situation,  Wht u r actually askng 2 do will take a min of a week to complete, moreover will exceed more than 500 lines of code, in different files aspx +  database + c# code..  Do you want me to post over 500+ lines of code here which would be in different classes & files. I will code it all for you.. you will just need to copy and paste in your project and i am doing this 'coz it will nourish my coding skills and nothing else. But u need to be supportive, I will start coding when u come up with a solution to this issue. else thank you.

Comment: have you created a custom rule using Microsoft Fxcop

Comment: just used an external library for manipulating pdf's "iTextSharp".. and then witten code to manipulate pdf documents and put them in class library and that's it. need help then email the question.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behavior is handled by the browsers itself, all you need to just flush pdf doc to browser (as suggested by GeekyCoder), and then depends on browser you will see document or will be presented with Save As dialog.

There is no native controls that will display pdf. In case you would like to be sure pdf is always displayed on page you would need to create control for it on your own (or maybe search for free/paid custom one).

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the PDF file in the browser (without download) requires an add-on to the client's browser. Google Chrome, for example, has a built-in PDF viewer and can open files directly, while IE and Firefox require that you install a plug-in (the one that comes with Adobe Reader).

There are two other approaches:

Convert the file to HTML, image, or any other format that can be directly viewed in the browser. This conversion can be on-the-fly using a server-side (written in PHP, Python, ASP, whatever language), or you can just pre-convert all files to a readable one.

The other approach, which is the best, is to use a Flash-based PDF viewer (such as http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/). This is easy, flexible and doesn't require writing server-side code. This approach is used by many Document-sharing sites (e.g. http://www.scribd.com/, http://www.slideshare.net/, http://www.docstoc.com/)